# Pressure Drop as a Predictor of Degree of Electrochemical Machining?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, flow, electrochemistry

I'm trying to get my head around the concept of electrochemical machining and if it would be possible to measure the pressure drop across a pipe as the process is ongoing at a given flow rate to ultimately calculate the amount the pipe has been eroded.

Would the Hagen-Poiseuille equation apply in such a setup?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If you know the reaction, the amount of material electrochemically removed can be determined by measuring the electrical current during the reaction. This should be a more robust method than using pressure drop.